# Not receiving response from WCF service in BizTalk

Tags: wcf, dataset, biztalk, biztalk-orchestrations

I am consuming a WCF service in BizTalk orchestration which returns a DataSet. I have tried to consume the service in ordinary way but couldn't succeeded. Please let me know is there any special way to handle a DataSet as response from WCF in BizTalk?

What I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to serialize the DataSet to xmlObject  before consuming it on BizTalk

Check this tutorial for example

[WCF-to-BizTalk-Passing-Typed-DataSet](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/47334/WCF-to-BizTalk-Passing-Typed-DataSet)

Comment: thanks for reply, actually I am using a service which I am unable to change or update. I have to use its data only. Do I have to write some intermediate code between service response and biztalk or.....?